# Integration of normal distribution using Simpson's rule

Tags: python, numpy, integration

I'm trying to perform a simple integration using the [scipy.integrate.simps](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html) function and I can't figure out the results it shows.

Here's a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

# Same normal function used by np.random.normal
def norm_func(x, mu, sigma):
    y = 1/(sigma*np.sqrt(2*np.pi))*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return y

# Generate some random points from the normal distribution.
a = np.random.normal(1., 0.1, 1000)

# Integrate the evaluated values of these points.
print simps(norm_func(a, 1., 0.1), a)
```

I would expect that since I'm drawing random numbers from a [normal distribution](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) and then integrating their evaluation in an equivalent normal distribution, I should get the result of integrating said normal distribution [which is 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%28%281/%28sqrt%282%2aPi%2a0.1%2a%2a2%29%29%29%2aexp%28-%28x-1%29%2a%2a2/%282%2a0.1%2a%2a2%29%29%29%20from%20x=0%20to%203) (or very close to it).

What I find instead is that the results appear to vary with the sample size of `a`. Even worst, if I set a value of 10000 in `a = np.random.normal(1., 0.1, 10000)`, the integration returns a *negative* value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your sample, just sort `a` first, since it should be an array of points to sample at, and it expects them to be in order to build the approximation.  Simpson's rule uses

[image: simpsons rule]

So it will be taking values for `x` from your array and evaluating the function.  If they are in a random order you can see that the above formula makes little sense, as it will do integrals from one random point on the domain to another.  It might be better to think of it as `x`, so I'll use that variable name:

```
x = np.random.normal(1., 0.1, 1000)
x.sort() # sorts in place
print simps(norm_func(x, 1., 0.1), x)
#0.999914876748
```

This also works for me:

```
s = np.sort(np.random.normal(1., 0.1, 10000))
print simps(norm_func(s, 1., 0.1), s)
#0.999943377731
```

Comment: I did try sorting the list but I used `sorted(a)` instead of `a.sort()` and it didn't work. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Perhaps you didn't save the output of `sorted`?  `a.sort()` sorts `a` inplace, so `a.sort()` is equivalent to `a = np.sort(a)` or, `a = np.array(sorted(a))`.  See my edit for a nice way to do that.

Comment: No, I did save the output. Could you please try it yourself so we can see if it's only me? This is what I did to sort the list: `a1 = sorted(a) / print simps(norm_func(a, 1., 0.1), a1)`.

Comment: Scratch that, I just realized I only changed the last `a` for `a1` and not the one used to call the normal function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can integrate the standard normal pdf using `simps`:

```
In [37]: a = np.linspace(-20, 20)

In [38]: print simps(norm_func(a, 0., 1.), a)
1.0
```